# How to count no of rows in where n no of columns containing the missing/NaN value in the same row in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

How to count no of rows in where n no of columns containing the missing/NaN value in the same row in pandas ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: can you please add an example?

Comment: Suppose there is a data frame having 10 columns and 100 rows. I want to count no of rows where n no of column is containing NaN value.  Basically the way we use while dropping a rows if i contains multiple NaN values using thresh parameter